# Threejs: how to extrude a single face of sphere?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I would like to extrude a single face from a sphere in Three.js:

Selecting the face:
[image]

Extruding the face:
[image]

Is this possible in Three.js ? How ?

I don’t really have a sphere but a IcosahedronGeometry. Should be the same I guess. Here is my Object:

```
earth = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(80, 2), m_earth);
scene.add(earth);
```

Since the earth object has a `.geometry.faces` array I thought I could somehow use these so manipulate the object. As I’m quite new to Three.js I can’t see how to select and manipulate one..

Thanks for your help.

€dit: I don’t want the user to be able to select the face nor to manipulate it. I just want to extrude inwards one specific face of the IcosahedronGeometry in three.js code.

Comment: You put a lot of effort in writing this question, which is a very good thing, but it is *much too broad*. Selecting the face is a separate question, controlling it with the mouse is a separate question, and manually manipulating the geometry for extrusion (indeed using geometry.faces, amongst other things) requires a fair bit of effort and then one or two questions if still needed. In general, geometry manipulation gets *hard* really fast, and is not suitable for a simple Q&A format.

Comment: Ok then it was not well formulated enough. I don’t want to select it with the mouse nor manually manipulate it. I just want to extrude one face with code but I don’t know how…

Comment: `var geometry = new THREE.IcosahedronBufferGeometry( 5, 0 ); geometry.attributes.position.array[ 45 ] *= 0.8; // repeat for [ 45 ] ... [ 53 ].`

Comment: @WestLangley Good hint (and nice use of the normal properties of a sphere), but do note (for the OP/future reader, I know you know your stuff :D) that such code is just *moving* the face, not extruding it in the 3D modelling sense. You have to add extra faces for the sides of the extruded face.

Comment: Note that "the face" in this case, is actually made of two faces (triangles). To make this task easier, 3D modelling applications hold a lot more information about the model than out-of-the-box three.js, like higher-order polygons, edges and connectivity over those edges. Solving the special case of two coplanar triangles in a three.js generated IcosahedronGeometry is definitely possible without all that, but it would come down to writing a chunk of code that is completely not extensible to a more generic case and having very little educational value. That said, I'll post code later today.

Comment: @Paul-Jan Agreed. Also, when moving the face, as in the image, you have to use a geometry that does not share vertices. Hence `IcosahedronBufferGeometry`.

Comment: @WestLangley, this looks interesting. But, what is .attributes.position.array and what is it actually changing?
Paul-Jan, looking forward for your solutions, you’re right, its missing the sides